# Необходимо постоянно опрашивать сервер с помощью клиента на go используя http json запрос

Tags: golang, httpclient

Хочу организовать типа текстового чата, с сервером все понятно, но не могу(не знаю), как заставить клиента написанного на GO, постоянно опрашивать сервер используя http json запрос. Суть в чем отправляем запрос на сервер - если ничего для данного клиента от других клиентов и сервера нет, то ничего не делаем - просто пишем в лог о успешном запросе, если есть то парсим ответ сервера от кого и что за текст нам пришел, и печатаем на стороне клиента данный текст из запроса и от кого он пришел. Как заставить данный код держать постоянное соединение с сервером ?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://127.0.0.1:10443"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)
    var dfdf int64 = 948727345
    dxdx := "15620eb732f93f81"
    erer := strconv.FormatInt(dfdf, 10)
    dcdc := "{\"Te\":\"" + string(erer) + "\",\"Na\":\"" + dxdx + "\",\"Mi\":\"" + dxdx + "\",\"Se\":\"" + dxdx + "\"}"
    fmt.Println("dcdc = ", dcdc)

    var jsonStr = []byte(dcdc)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        panic(err)

    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}
```

Comment: у http нет постоянного соединения. а что мешает вам зациклить запрос `client.Do` чтобы постоянно вызывался?

Comment: Можно и так сделать, думал что имеются более продвинутые решения для данной задачи

Comment: web sockets, events. надо чтобы не ты запрашивал данные, а тебе присылали

Comment: Обычное stream сокет-соединение, через, как уже сказано выше, [websockets](https://yalantis.com/blog/how-to-build-websockets-in-go/), либо [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/)